# Virtual Methods & Object Slicing in c#

Tags: c#, virtual-functions

I can understand the basic object slicing ,but sometimes it's becoming much confusing
when we come to examples like that one

```
using System;
class A
{
   public virtual void F() { Console.WriteLine("A.F"); }
}
class B: A
{
   public override void F() { Console.WriteLine("B.F"); }
}
class C: B
{
   new public virtual void F() { Console.WriteLine("C.F"); }
}
class D: C
{
   public override void F() { Console.WriteLine("D.F"); }
}
class Test
{
   static void Main() {
      D d = new D();
      A a = d;
      B b = d;
      C c = d;
      a.F();
      b.F();
      c.F();
      d.F();
   }
}
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
B.F
B.F
D.F
D.F
```

i want to know how the "f()" function of class B is reached

```
D d = new D();
A a = d;
a.F();
```

while if it were :

```
A a = new A();
a.F()
//The result would be => A.F
```

however in the first part the "a" has a run time object of "d" so one might think it would be "D.F" as output ,so how it came along D and c and and B so the right output is "B.F"
Please help me to work this out

Comment: You might want to ask a question.

Comment: Explain why you expect to see something else. The used combinations of virtual, override and new cause to happen exactly what happens.

Comment: thank i have added some explanation , i hope it helps

Comment: You can't get object slicing in C#.

Comment: Article on slicing: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2006/03/24/559195.aspx "There is no call by-value for reference types and hence the whole story of slicing is suddenly not there."

Comment: @user2586804 You can explain it more

Comment: I can't explain it any better than the blog does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `new` to define a method with the same name as a base class' method, you *hide* the base class' implementation. (This is almost always a bad idea, but very occasionally necessary.)

When you reference a class with a hidden method like this, it's not an override. Because of this, the variable type that you use to refer to the object will dictate which version of the method you'll get.

When you reference your `new D()` through either `a` or `b`, you're referencing it as a type that doesn't know about the `new` version of the method. Therefore both of these calls use the most derived version of the method that they *do* know about. There is no override for `B.F()` in either `C` (because it's `new`) or `D` (because it only overrides the method in `C`). Therefore, `B.F()` is called in both of these cases.

When you reference the class through `c` or `d`, the overridden method in `D` is used, as you would expect.

Answer (score 5):

Well, AMAIK, your question is essentially not about object slicing. It's more about the difference between using `new`, `virtual` and `override` keywords.

I'll bring forward a more understandable example. Consider this code:

```
public class Animal
{
    public virtual void Sleep()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(@"I'm an animal, and I want to sleep.
        I just close my eyes");
    }
}

public class Mammal : Animal
{
    public override void Sleep()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(@"I'm a mammal, thus basically an animal.
        Therefore, I both close my eyes, and need a warm place to sleep");
    }

    public bool HasBreasts
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}

public class Human : Mammal
{
    public new virtual void Sleep()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(@"I'm a human. 
        I'm so proud that I don't consider myself as an animal. 
        I sleep in a cozy place, 
        and I need a lot of money to sleep well");
    }

    public virtual void FallInLove();
}

public class Worker : Human
{
    public override void Sleep()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(@"I'm a worker, and I'm under poverty line. 
        I have to work hard, 
        and I really don't know what they mean by a good sleep");
    }

    public override void FallInLove()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(@"What is love? 
        I need bread to survive. 
        I'm in the bottom-most level of Mozlow's pyramid of needs.");
    }
}
```

Now let's analyze each keyword. Since a `Worker` is basically and essentially a human, thus it `HasBreasts` and also it can `FallInLove()`. But wait a minute. A worker (no offense, just a funny example) has no money to fall in love. Then a worker might `override` this very behavior, and forget about love.

On the other hand, all animals can sleep. They only close their eyes to sleep. However, since Mammals are hot blooded, they need a warm place. So they extend their ancestor's habit of sleeping.

But human on the other hand, defined a completely `new` level of sleeping. He wants a revolution against his ancestors. He doesn't want to be known as an `Animal`, so he redefines `Sleep()` from scratch.

Now based on explanations of @DanPuzey, you can read rest of the story. It makes sense in the real-world.

Comment: What's missing is if you have a `Human` or `Worker` and treat (reference) them as `Animal`s or `Mamal`s then they once again behave like `Mamal`s as the `new Sleep()` will not be called.

Comment: i.e. `Animal a = new Human(); a.Sleep();` will yield `Mamal`s response because you are invoking the original incarnation of `Sleep()`

Comment: Yeah, if you do it like `Mammal mammal = new Human();` and call `mammal.Sleep();`, since `Human` has defined a completely different and `new` level of sleeping, thus `mammal` can't do that and does what it knows, i.e., sleeping like a mammal in a warm place.